# Update part of a JavaFx WritableImage with a AWT BufferedImage

Tags: javafx, bufferedimage

I'm trying to efficiently update a large WritableImage with multiple smaller tiles which are received as AWT BufferedImage instances.

Things I've tried:

- I can use SwingFXUtils to convert the BufferedImage to a WritableImage, however there is no simple API on Writable image to take the pixels from another WritableImage that I can figure out.
- I can get the pixels out of BufferedImage as an int [] using getData().getPixels(....).

  However WritableImage expects data to be tightly packed in a single integers i.e. {ARGB, ARGB, ...} whereas BufferedImage.getData.getPixels returns data as series of integers, i.e. {R, G, B, A,   R, G, B, A, ...).

  I could obviously coerce the data into the correct format, but this doesn't feel very efficient.

I've after an approach / pointers on which API to use, I'm happy coding myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a version of [PixelWriter.setPixels](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html#setPixels(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20javafx.scene.image.PixelReader,%20int,%20int)) which takes another PixelReader as input.

```
private void update(Image input, WritableImage output, int x, int y) {
  int width = input.getWidth(null);
  int height = input.getHeight(null);

  WritableImage temp = new WritableImage(width, height); // same size as input
  SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(fragment, temp);

  output.getPixelWriter().setPixels(x, y, width, height, temp.getPixelReader(), 0, 0);
}
```